# Catenation and decatenation by DNA Gyrase

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, molecular-genetics

Decatenation is done for the replication of DNA and why is Catenation done and is it related to Crossing over

Answer (score 1):

Both DNA Catenation & Decatenation are crucial to the equal distribution of DNA to the daughter cells during the mitotic crossing over. While catenation plays structural role in chromosomal architecture , decatenation facilitates the separation of sister chromatids.

Comment: Hi Jank. Can you add some details with some references?